# Delete sql table rows from python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, delete-row

I can successfully connect my python notebook with sql server this way :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('''DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                                    SERVER= SERVER_NAME;
                                    DATABASE= DATABASE_NAME;
                                    TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;''')

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params,case_sensitive=False)
```

Let's take this sample dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name=['abc','def','ghi'],Date=['2018-08-15','2019-08-15','2020-08-15'],Status=[True,False,True],Max=[0,0,8]))

  Name        Date  Status  Max
0  abc  2018-08-15    True    0
1  def  2019-08-15   False    0
2  ghi  2020-08-15    True    8
```

I have a sql table with the same columns, named table_name.

**Objective :**

I want to delete in table_name all the rows where a row in df has the same Name, same Date, same Status, and Max = 0 (only in table_name, not necessary in df)

**I tried the following but it doesn't work :**

```
connection = engine.raw_connection()
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_Delete_query = """Delete from table_name where Date = %s AND Name = %s AND Status = %s AND Max = 0"""
        cursor.execute(sql_Delete_query, (row['Date'],row['Name'],row['Status']))
        connection.commit()
    except:
        error = True
```

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong ?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Your `except` block hides all information about the error.

Comment: @Lamu it means that I always have error = True whereas some rows in table_name are expected to be deleted

Comment: @khelwood what do you advise me to do ?

Comment: Take out the try/except and let the code error, see what it says.

Comment: I get this error :
('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: I am not familiar with %s so It might be the error, I tried to build the code from some code I found on forums

Comment: Change the `%s` in your SQL to `?` and see if that helps. Different libraries use different placeholders.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood, that was the solution !

Comment: Could you please write a quick answer in order to I close this post ?

Comment: *"@Lamu it means that I always have error "* `l a r n u`, no `m`, @Ewdlam . And if there is an error then you need to include that in your question. "It doesn't work" could mean anything without context.

Comment: @Larnu sorry for the error and you're right, I'll think about it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different libraries use different symbols for their placeholders. The one you are using apparently uses `?` instead of `%s`.

```
sql_Delete_query = """Delete from table_name where Date = ? AND Name = ? AND Status = ? AND Max = 0"""
```